# Ordering the list (of questions) with the suitable knowledge matching to the users knowledge

Tags: feature-request

There are different users with different knowledge. Professional users don't want to answer easy questions and amateur users are not able to answer difficult questions and so on.

If the questions were listed in order such that they were closest to the users knowledge then they could be more productive, because in this matter the user doesn't need to look through all questions to find one they can answer. The questions will be already listed specially for each user. So they log in; takes 1-2 minutes; and sees matching questions they can answer.

Comment: Please clarify your request; I can't tell *what* you're asking for.

Comment: How exactly would the difficulty of a question be assessed? Or the knowledge of the potential answerers for that matter?

Comment: This would just divide the community up - I don't think this is really something that is suitable and defeats the point of having a question and answer site where both new people and "professionals" are able to contribute.

Comment: By the way; just to pre-empt any problems; downvotes on meta mean "We disagree" or "We don't want this implemented" not necessarily “ this is a bad question (although some paragraphs and capital letters at the start of sentences wouldn’t go amiss).

Comment: It would be nice, but it's not very practical (at least not on the surface). Feel free to try to come up with a practical way to implement this, without drifting too far from the way the system currently works, keeping in mind that reputation isn't equivalent to ability - I've seen a few nice answers by new users and getting high-rep from answering easy questions doesn't necessarily make you much better.

Comment: this is just a idea a suggestion that crossed over my mind.

Comment: And we're glad to hear them, keep them coming. Some people will like, some they won't

Comment: thank you @RichardTingle. thats for sure, i respect every thought and everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Technical difficulties

#### Assessing question difficulty

This would be extremely difficult to implement; how would a questions difficulty be assessed? If it was selected by the question answerer then there would be a strong tendency to suggest your question was more difficult that it is to gain more expert views.

#### Assessing user expertise

Although rep is a very broad marker of knowledge in a subject area it does not differentiate the ability to answer difficult questions very well or easy questions very well. As such this could lead to a user who answers many easy questions to a high standard being effectively locked out of stack exchange forever because they are only ever shown very difficult questions

## Problems with assumptions

#### We want expert answers to all our questions

The best and most complete answers to basic questions come from expert users; they are complete and 100% accurate rather than; sort of working. These are the sorts of answers we want, we don't want our experts locked away in ivory towers while people who don't really know what they are doing are the only people allowed to answer the questions that 99% of people will care about

#### Maybe experts don't mind helping with basic questions

It is an assumption to assume that experts don't want to answer basic questions. Ultimately the heavy answerers are here to share their knowledge and teach; a basic (non duplicate) question is an excellent opportunity to share knowledge

#### Maybe non experts don't mind seeing hard questions

I have learned a great many things by being exposed to difficult question that I could never answer (but now can after reading the answers!). I would be sad to lose that!

Comment: ... and people who don't know what they're doing will likely also be voting, thus a completely wrong answer can get voted up to infinity.

Comment: my post was just a thought. something like a difficulty tag and perhaps a additional button that says "suitable questions for me". and when the user clicks it then he will get the questions reordered that are suitable to his profile and difficulty range. of course he should be still able to see and answer all questions just the order was what i meant. this was just my thought i shared. but now i agree with you.